# Improving MySQLdb load data infile performance

Tags: python, pandas, innodb, mysql-python

I have a table that's roughly defined as follows in InnoDB:

```
create table `my_table` (
  `time` int(10) unsigned not null,
  `key1` int(10) unsigned not null,
  `key3` char(3) unsigned not null,
  `key2` char(2) unsigned not null,
  `value1` float default null,
  `value2` float default null,
  primary key (`key1`, `key2`, `key3`, `time`),
  key (`key3`, `key2`, `key1`, `time`)
) engine=InnoDB default character set ascii
partition by range(time) (
  partition start        values less than (0),
  partition from20180101 values less than (unix_timestamp('2018-02-01')),
  partition from20180201 values less than (unix_timestamp('2018-03-01')),
  ...,
  partition future       values less than MAX_VALUE
)
```

Yes, the column order doesn't match the key order.

In Python I'm populating a DataFrame with 500,000 rows (this is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but serves as a sample for what the data may look like):

```
import random
import pandas as pd
key2_values = ["aaa", "bbb", ..., "ttt"]  # 20 distinct values
key3_values = ["aa", "ab", "ac", ..., "az", "bb", "bc", ..., "by"]  # 50 distinct values
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=["key1", "key2", "key3", "value2", "value1"])
idx = 0
for x in range(0, 500):
    for y in range(0, 20):
        for z in range(0, 50):
            df.loc[idx] = [x, key2_values[y], key3_values[z], random.random(), random.random()]
            idx += 1
df.set_index(["key1", "key2", "key3"], inplace=True)
```

(In reality this DataFrame is populated from several API calls and a lot of math, but the end result is the same: a huge DataFrame with ~500,000 rows and keys matching the InnoDB table)

To import this DataFrame into the table, I'm currently doing the following:

```
import time
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(local_infile=1, **connection_params)
cur = conn.cursor()
# Disable data integrity checks -- I know the data is good
cur.execute("SET foreign_key_checks=0;")
cur.execute("SET unique_checks=0;")
# Append current time to the DataFrame
df["time"] = time.time()
df.set_index(["time"], append=True, inplace=True)
# Sort data in primary key order
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
# Dump the data to a CSV
with open("dump.csv", "w") as csv:
    df.to_csv(csv)
# Load the data
cur.execute(
    """
        load data local infile 'dump.csv'
        into table `my_table`
        fields terminated by ','
        enclosed by '"'
        lines terminated by '\n'
        ignore 1 lines
        (`key1`, `key2`, `key3`, `time`, `value`)
    """
)
# Clean up
cur.execute("SET foreign_key_checks=1;")
cur.execute("SET unique_checks=1;")
conn.commit()
```

In all the performance on this isn't too bad. I can import 500,000 rows in about 2 minutes. If possible I want to get this faster.

Are there any tricks I'm missing or any changes I could make to get this down to 30-45 seconds?

Some notes:

- I don't know if reordering the **columns** in the DataFrame will affect performance. Currently the order of columns in the DataFrame does not match the database
- I don't know if changing the order of the columns in the database to match the order of the primary key will affect performance (currently "time" comes first, even though it's the fourth key of the index)
- Altering the database config could be difficult, as I don't have direct access to the database server. I'm stuck with whatever hardware and configuration options are already present. Any performance improvements must come from my Python code
- I **can** change the table definition (including changing the partitioning) however I would like to avoid this if possible as there is already a large amount of historic data and copying it to another table would take a long time. Losing this data is an option, but one I'd rather avoid
- I cannot use `set sql_log_bin=0;` because I do not have the `SUPER` privilege on the database

Comment: Since you don't have SUPER privilege, is this an RDS instance? If so, what's the EBS volume size? If it's small, you might not have enough IOPS by default. On my Macbook, I can get ~50,000 rows per second using LOAD DATA INFILE. See my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: It's actually an internal MariaDB server managed by the DBAs at my company. I can technically submit a Jira ticket asking them to tweak the settings, but it takes 2-3 weeks to get a response and the response is usually a negative. Unfortunately I don't know the details of the server (disk size, disk I/O, etc)

Comment: Well it sounds like it's running on hardware that is either very low-performance, or perhaps subjected to high load already. Either way, it's not a problem that can be fixed on Stack Overflow. There's no change in Python code that can make LOAD DATA INFILE run faster than the database server can run.

Comment: That's not strictly true. Loading data in the primary key order improves `LOAD DATA INFILE` performance, as does `SET unique_checks=0;`. I'm performing a test now to see if adjusting the keys so that `time` is the left-most primary key will improve performance even further (since all rows being inserted share a time)

Comment: Are you writing a csv with 500K rows?  Or some smaller chunk?  How much of the 2 minutes is building the csv; how much is the LOAD DATA?

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: How many partitions are there now?  How many will there ultimately be?  (20-50 is a good range.)

Comment: Am I missing something, or are you not providing `time` when building the CSV??

Comment: @RickJames I'm building a CSV with 500k rows. The construction of the CSV and writing the CSV to disk takes less than 0.5 seconds (tested). I do not know the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` because I do not have admin rights on the database. If I can read this value without admin rights, let me know how and I can answer that question. There are currently 17 partitions. I plan on only ever having 17 (I delete a partition whenever I make a new one). `time` is added to the DataFrame on the 9th line of the Python code, and the CSV is built from the DataFrame. Other questions?

Comment: @RickJames `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is `128M`. I don't know how much RAM is on the server

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size`;` does not need admin priv.  Also `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;`

Comment: @RickJames I figured that out and made a comment with the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. As I said, it's 128 megabytes. I do not know how many megabytes of RAM the server has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made three changes and I didn't stop to measure performance between each change, so I can't be **100%** certain the exact impact of each change, however I can be reasonably sure I know what had the bigger impact.

### Change 1 (pretty sure this had the biggest impact) -- Modified primary key

Looking at how my script operates, you can see that all 500k rows I'm bulk inserting have the exact same value for `time`:

```
# Append current time to the DataFrame
df["time"] = time.time
```

By making `time` the left-most column of the primary key meant that all of the rows I was inserting would be clustered together, rather than having to split them across the table.

Of course the problem with this is that it makes the index useless for my most common query: returning all "times" for a given `key1`, `key2`, and `key3` combination (e.g.: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE key1 = ... AND key2 = ... AND key3 = ...`)

To fix this, I had to add another key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`time`, `key1`, `key2`, `key3`),
KEY (`key1`, `key2`, `key3`)
```

### Change 2 (may have had an impact) -- Modified column order

I adjusted the table so that the order of the columns matched the order of the primary key (`time`, `key1`, `key2`, `key3`)

I don't know if this had an effect, but it might have

### Change 3 (may have had an impact) -- Adjusted the order of columns in the CSV

I ran the following on my DataFrame:

```
df.reindex(columns=["value1", "value2"], inplace=True)
```

This sorted the columns to match the order they appeared in the database. Between this and change 2, the rows could be imported exactly as they were without needing to swap the order of columns. I don't know if that has any impact on import performance

### Result

With these three changes my import is down from 2 minutes to 9 seconds! **That's absolutely incredible**

I was worried about adding the extra key to the table since additional indexes means longer write times and more disk space, but the effect was almost negligible -- especially compared to the massive savings I got from clustering my key correctly.

Comment: Well done! I would have expected the primary key order to be better, but not by that much.

Comment: I will note that rearranging the primary key gave an incredible boost to my write performance, but has hurt my read performance pretty badly. It used to take 2-3 seconds to run my common query (return all "times" for a given set of keys). Now it takes 30 seconds to run the same query. Although I don't like this, we write **far** more often than we read with this database, so it's acceptable.

Comment: @stevendesu - tack `time` onto the index being used for that `SELECT`; this will make it a "covering" index, hence much faster.

Comment: @RickJames I will test out adding `time` to the index being used for the `SELECT`, but I doubt I will see a huge performance gain. I'm already able to run my `SELECT` statement very quickly. If there's a big improvement I'll be sure to let you know.