# Improving MySQL SELECT performance

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

### The setup

I have a database which will ultimately contain 13 billion rows. The rows are keyed on 4 values: `(asn, cty (country), src (source), time)`.

There are roughly 60,000 distinct values for `asn`, roughly 200 distinct values for `country`, and roughly 55 distinct values for `source` -- although not all triplets are valid. There are roughly 500,000 valid triplets.

For each valid triplet I record data into a database once every 5 minutes, with `time` being the time the data was recorded. After 90 days we delete data off the end. This yield `12 (iterations per hour) * 24 (hours) * 90 (days) = 25920 rows per (asn, country, source) tuple`

My metrics table currently looks like so:

```
create table `metrics` (
  `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `asn` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cty` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `src` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `reqs` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rtt` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `rexb` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `nae` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `util` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time`, `asn`, `cty`, `src`),
  KEY (`asn`, `cty`, `src`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET ascii
partition by range(time) (
  PARTITION start        VALUES LESS THAN (0),
  PARTITION from20171224 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31')),
  PARTITION from20171231 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-07')),
  PARTITION from20180107 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-14')),
  PARTITION from20180114 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-21')),
  PARTITION from20180121 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-28')),
  PARTITION from20180128 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-04')),
  PARTITION from20180204 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-11')),
  PARTITION from20180211 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-18')),
  PARTITION from20180218 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-25')),
  PARTITION from20180225 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-04')),
  PARTITION from20180304 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-11')),
  PARTITION from20180311 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-18')),
  PARTITION from20180318 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-25')),
  PARTITION from20180325 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-04-01')),
  PARTITION future       VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

I also have a "thresholds" table which records what a "good RTT" looks like and what a "bad RTT" looks like at any given time interval:

```
create table `thresholds` (
  `time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rtt_good` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `rtt_bad` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
  `rexb_good` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `rexb_bad` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
  `nae_good` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `nae_bad` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
  `util_good` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `util_bad` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
partition by range(time) (
  PARTITION start        VALUES LESS THAN (0),
  PARTITION from20171224 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-12-31')),
  PARTITION from20171231 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-07')),
  PARTITION from20180107 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-14')),
  PARTITION from20180114 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-21')),
  PARTITION from20180121 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-28')),
  PARTITION from20180128 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-04')),
  PARTITION from20180204 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-11')),
  PARTITION from20180211 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-18')),
  PARTITION from20180218 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-25')),
  PARTITION from20180225 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-04')),
  PARTITION from20180304 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-11')),
  PARTITION from20180311 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-18')),
  PARTITION from20180318 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-25')),
  PARTITION from20180325 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-04-01')),
  PARTITION future       VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

### The query

Now one of the most common queries that I perform on this data involves returning weighted averages **for each time** for a given asn, or country, or asn+country pair. It looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.time * 1000 as time,
    @rtt := coalesce(m_sum.weighted_rtt, @rtt) as rtt,
    floor(least(100, greatest(0,
        100 * (coalesce(m_sum.weighted_rtt, @rtt) - t.rtt_bad) / (t.rtt_good - t.rtt_bad)
    ))) as rtt_quality,
    @util := coalesce(m_sum.weighted_util, @util) as util,
    floor(least(100, greatest(0,
        100 * (coalesce(m_sum.weighted_util, @util) - t.util_bad) / (t.util_good - t.util_bad)
    ))) as util_quality
FROM
    thresholds as t
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            m.time,
            sum(m.rtt*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_rtt,
            sum(m.util*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_util
        FROM metrics AS m
        WHERE m.asn = '7018' and m.cty = 'us'
        GROUP BY m.time
    ) AS m_sum ON t.time = m_sum.time
ORDER BY t.time asc;
```

And it returns something like this:

```
+---------------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------+
| time          | rtt     | rtt_quality | util     | util_quality |
+---------------+---------+-------------+----------+--------------+
| 1521234900000 | NULL    | NULL        | NULL     | NULL         |
| 1521235200000 | 45      | 80          | 3000     | 40           |
| 1521235500000 | 45      | 80          | 3000     | 40           |
| 1521235800000 | 65      | 70          | 2000     | 60           |
| 1521236100000 | 65      | 70          | 2000     | 60           |
| 1521236400000 | 65      | 70          | 2000     | 60           |
| 1521236700000 | 65      | 70          | 2000     | 60           |
| 1521237000000 | 120     | 50          | 4500     | 10           |
      ...           ...         ...         ...           ...
```

Breaking this query down, we:

1. Filter for only the rows we care about (based on `asn` and `cty` in this case)
2. Aggregate these values for every `time` - computing weighted metrics
3. Join these aggregated results with a table that contains "threshold" values for every given time (maybe at 5am we consider 100ms to be really poor RTT, but at 5pm when everyone is watching Netflix we consider 100ms pretty good)
4. Sort by `time`
5. If we don't have a recorded metric for a given time (maybe we didn't deliver traffic to that `asn`+`cty` pair for that 5-minute interval) then use the previous 5-minute interval's value (using user-defined variables)
6. Compute a "relative goodness" value (`*_quality`) for each metric

### The variables

My goal is to get this `SELECT` query as fast as possible. I can change:

- My `SELECT` query
- The table schema
- The table engine (I have access to MyISAM, InnoDB, and MariaDB's Columnstore)
- The table index
- The partitions

I cannot change:

- The database server
- The database configuration

### Previous tests

I previously did some tests using only about 150 million rows (1% of the final data set - included 300 distinct `time` values as opposed to the full 25920) and it seemed like InnoDB was the fastest - outperforming Columnstore by 3-4x (InnoDB returned data in approximately 0.7 seconds, Columnstore took approximately 2.5 seconds).

I believe this was true because the **very first** thing we do is filter out the majority of these 150 million rows before any aggregation or other work is done. InnoDB supports indexes which allows me to quickly find the rows I want to filter for and only work with those -- never reading the other data from disk.

Here's the catch, though: I now have 5 billion rows (roughly 40% of the final data set) and I ran the same performance comparison. This time, Columnstore seemed 2x faster than InnoDB! (30 seconds vs 60 seconds for InnoDB)

At least, it was faster the first time I ran a query for a particular `asn`+`country`. InnoDB seemed to have intermediate caching because I could then run additional queries with the same `asn`+`country` and they completed in under 1 second, but even running the **exact same** query in Columnstore took another 30 seconds

### The question(s)

1. Why is Columnstore going faster than InnoDB, even though Columnstore doesn't support indexes (and therefore we have to scan the **entire** table)?
2. Am I doing something wrong in either my table definition or my query that could be slowing this down? Thanks to InnoDB's indexing I should only need to read a handful of rows from disk. I don't know why it takes a full minute to do so
3. Does anyone have additional performance tips they can provide, unrelated to the two previous questions?

In an ideal world I would like this query to return in under 10 seconds with the full data set of 13 billion rows - although if that's not possible then returning in under 60 seconds is acceptable.

### One additional note

I have the ability to compute pre-aggregated values and store them in separate tables. I already do this to a small extent. I have three tables: `metrics_by_asn`, `metrics_by_cty`, and `metrics_by_time`. The first two store weighted averages of metrics and are keyed only on `(asn, time)` or `(cty, time)`. This effectively reduces this query:

```
SELECT
    m.time,
    sum(m.rtt*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_rtt,
    sum(m.util*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_util
FROM metrics AS m
WHERE m.asn = '7018'
GROUP BY m.time
```

To this one:

```
SELECT
    m.time,
    weighted_rtt,
    weighted_util
FROM metrics_by_asn AS m
WHERE m.asn = '7018'
```

The third table `metrics_by_time` returns summary statistics like the maximum RTT, average RTT, count of rows, etc.

I did not create a `metrics_by_asn_and_cty` table for two reasons. First, I did not expect to see incredible performance gains. On average, a particular `asn`+`cty` pair is only served from 1.3 distinct sources. Therefore most of the time pre-aggregating this wouldn't reduce the number of rows we need to select. Second, we're already hitting some major disk usage limits. Looking at our metrics table alone we have 13 billion rows times roughly 35 bytes per row. That's 455 **gigabytes** for this database. Add in the pre-aggregated tables and additional tables where we dump the raw data used to compute these metrics, and we're sitting around 850 gigabytes on disk. I haven't been told a hard limit on how much data I'm allowed to store, but I'm trying to stay under a terabyte to be safe.

Comment: Bug:  `1521234900000` won't fit in an `INT`??

Comment: Is `time` always exactly on a 5-minute mark?

Comment: @RickJames `1521234900000` is the result of multiplying the stored value by `1000` (as shown in the select statement). Dividing by 1000 yields what's actually stored in the int: 1521234900 - a valid unix timestamp.

Comment: @RickJames `time` is always exactly on a 5-minute mark. The code which puts this data into the database rounds to the nearest multiple of 300 before saving

Comment: As long as you are playing with a factor of 1000, you may as well throw in another 300.  This would let you shrink the column to 3 bytes -- `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`.

Comment: @RickJames I'll consider it. Currently what's stored in the database is a unix timestamp. I'm multiplying by 1000 because the results of the query I'm running will be handed to JavaScript to draw a graph, and JavaScript uses milliseconds instead of seconds. Saving a byte does sound nice, but I don't know if it's worth making the database less human-readable. We occasionally run queries on this database manually when exploring issues.

Comment: Add a simple pair of Stored Functions to convert between the MEDIUMINT for 5-minute values and unix timestamp (or datetime).  (I did this in an app that had 1-hour values.  It was not too bad.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show the CREATE TABLE in your post, which is good, but you don't mention any other query analysis. When you're investigating query optimization, you should consider:

- [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execution-plan-information.html) to see the query optimization plan, and how the optimizer chooses to use indexes
- [Query profiling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html)
- [PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/performance-schema-overview/)
- SYS schema [for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html) or [for MariaDB](https://github.com/good-dba/mariadb-sys)

I tried testing EXPLAIN at least for your subquery. By the way, column `pop` is mentioned in your index but does not appear in your table, so you haven't posted the real CREATE TABLE.

I got this:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT m.time, sum(m.rtt*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_rtt, 
sum(m.util*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_util FROM metrics AS m 
WHERE m.asn = '7018' and m.cty = 'us' GROUP BY m.time\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,asn,bk1
          key: asn
      key_len: 6
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Notice that only the first two columns of your asn index are used, as indicated by `const,const`. Also the `Using temporary; Using filesort` often indicates a costly overhead for a query.

I got better when I added an index:

```
mysql> alter table metrics add index bk1 (asn,cty,time);
```

I had to use an index hint to persuade the MySQL optimizer to use my index. This may be necessary only because I had no rows of data in my table, so the optimizer wasn't able to analyze which index would be better.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT m.time, sum(m.rtt*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_rtt, 
sum(m.util*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_util FROM metrics AS m use index(bk1) 
WHERE m.asn = '7018' and m.cty = 'us' GROUP BY m.time\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,asn,bk1
          key: bk1
      key_len: 6
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

The temp table / filesort is gone. This is because the GROUP BY can execute in index order once I put the `time` column following the two columns used for filtering.

Finally I tried to create an index that included all the columns referenced in the subquery:

```
mysql> alter table metrics add index bk2 (asn,cty,time,rtt,reqs,util);

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT m.time, sum(m.rtt*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_rtt, 
sum(m.util*m.reqs)/sum(m.reqs) AS weighted_util FROM metrics AS m use index(bk2) 
WHERE m.asn = '7018' and m.cty = 'us' GROUP BY m.time\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: m
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,asn,bk1,bk2
          key: bk2
      key_len: 6
          ref: const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

The `Using index` is a good sign. This is called a "covering index" which means the query was able to get all the columns it needed just by reading the index, without having to read the table at all. This is a useful technique.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

You mention that you can't change the MySQL configuration options, but you don't say what the options are. One of the important options is the InnoDB buffer pool size. Without a sufficiently sized buffer pool, your query will force a lot of I/O as it swaps pages of indexes into RAM and back out again.

I have no experience with the MariaDB column store, so I can't comment on its features, or how to monitor or tune it. You might want to engage with MariaDB services.

I agree with James Scheller's answer that pre-aggregating partial results and storing it is important, and may be the only way to address this problem. Some column stores I've read about do this automatically, pre-calculating various aggregate results for each partition. I have no idea what the MariaDB column store does.

Comment: Regarding the "pop" column, that was a copy/paste error on my end. "pop" was at one point renamed to "src" (pop = point of presence, one of our data centers) -- I have countless text files on my desktop with create table queries and select queries since I've been experimenting and developing and they aren't all updated with new column names yet

Comment: Thanks for all of the great tips. I'm working now to try and implement them and see what kind of performance improvements I get. Unfortunately with 5 billion rows of data it's nearly impossible (maybe actually impossible?) to drop an index and create a new one. So I may have to make a whole new table, start dumping data there for a week, then see how it performs after a week

Comment: Not impossible, unless you don't have enough disk space. I support some MySQL databases that are over 2TB.

Comment: I've updated the config file on my script to start dumping data to a new table (with the new indexes) and I started a `create index` query running to update the old table. It's been going for 12 minutes now - no idea how long it will take. We'll see if it completes before I get kicked off of VPN or my connection is broken. Worst-case scenario I have data filtering into the new table so in a few days I can measure the performance. I'll also monitor the write performance to see if the larger index is costing me too much on that front.

Comment: Note that you might not need *all* the indexes. I suggested `bk1` and `bk2` as alternatives.

Comment: After 13525 seconds I lost my connection to the database server and the attempt to add a new index failed. I have had my script running for a little while now and I have 22 million rows already in the new tables. Although even with the new covering index it took 0.24 seconds to run my query. Assuming that scales up linearly we're looking at about the same speed we saw before. I'll wait until we have more data to say anything definitely, though.

Comment: Are you using `EXPLAIN` to confirm that it's using the new index?

Comment: It is using the new index (`Extra: Using where; Using index
`). It could be that there's a high start-up cost to the query and it won't scale linearly now that it's using the index. In a week when I have more data I'll be able to verify if the new index resolved my performance concerns.

Comment: Okay, good. Anyway, as James and I suggested, I suspect that refactoring the query to use some kind of pre-aggregation would be more effective at improving the query time.

Comment: It turns out despite getting disconnected, the statement kept running in the background. I noticed today that the new index was in place. I tested out my select statement and with the new covering index it was down from 60 seconds to 1.3!

Comment: It might run even faster with the PK ordered this way:  `PRIMARY KEY(asn, cty, time, src)`

Comment: @RickJames Re-arranging the primary key improves read performance at a severe penalty to write performance. Since the script writes data every 5 minutes, if the write does not complete within 5 minutes then we have a problem. if the read takes 5 minutes, we can survive. Therefore I optimized first for writes, THEN for reads.

Comment: @stevendesu - If `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is big enough, there should be virtually no difference in the write speed.  Are you finding otherwise?

Comment: @RickJames I found drastically otherwise. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327363/improving-mysqldb-load-data-infile-performance

Answer (score 1):

I used to work on a system that aggregated billing data for telephone calls, hundreds of millions of calls per day, so I've seen something similar to what you're describing.

Part of the issue with tree-based indexes is that as you get very large number of rows in the table, the indexes themselves can become quite large and deep. Even if your index keys are fairly compact, you can create a very deep (and quantifiably large) set of nodes that have to be traversed to navigate the index to find table rows. This may involve a lot more disk and memory bandwidth than you would expect, and if the index itself is substantially larger than the actual data, it may wind up having poorer performance than something that blindly reads the table anyway.

There's always a sweet spot. If a table is exceedingly small, or exceedingly large, indexes aren't necessarily an easy fix.

For this telecom billing application, we absolutely had to pre-aggregate the data. In fact we did in it in multiple tiers with different criteria effectively so that the reporting layers in the application could efficiently grab data by whatever criteria it needed for different business cases (by geography, business partner, etc). Those tables wound up being small enough (hundreds of thousands of rows) that conventional indexing was very efficient.

However in that business case, we were doing lots of batch updates, so we would process thousands of rows and could aggregate lots of data in-memory during that process, then do only a relatively small number of updates to the tables that track the aggregates. It was quite efficient, but it was very much tuned to that sort of usage.

Comment: Is this issue exclusive to tree-based indexes? If InnoDB supports hash indexes (I'm not sure if it does, but I'll look that up now) I can change my index type. There's no real reason I need to use a B-tree. I'm not sorting by ASN or anything.

Comment: @stevendesu, [InnoDB does not support HASH indexes.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/storage-engine-index-types/)

Comment: @stevendesu, I'm not sure what this looks like with InnoDB as an engine. That telecom thing used Oracle. It may be some other indexing architectures are efficient enough, but your test data sounds hauntingly familiar...